# One index.js file in fulfillment dialogflow with multiple functions/trigger to firestore #AskFirebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I have the code below in the dialogflow ("firebase-functions": **"^ 3.7.0"**
**and node: 10**)
[DialogFlow index.js with issue](https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/2bff2675d119e5431018848535a94c37)
[Photos project in DialogFlow](https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1qXVx9ojFkRoKTKjCdXvZqemyNC4o041s?usp=sharing)

1. I have four intents: Ligar, Desligar, Abrir e Fechar (all with fulfillment enabled)
2. I not have issue in **deploy** or in execution(logs cloud functions), but the only function that works is **getLigar().** How to solve this?

```
    'use strict';
    
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    const db = admin.firestore();
    
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
    
    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      const agent = new WebhookClient({request, response});
    
      function getLigar(agent) {
        var gpioalarmstateb = agent.parameters;
        return db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').get()
          .then(doc => {
            const xalarmstate = doc.data().gpioalarmstate;
            if (!xalarmstate) {
              db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').update({
                gpioalarmstate: true
              })
            }
            agent.add(`Gpioalarmstate is ${gpioalarmstateb} xalarmstate is  ${xalarmstate}.`);
          });
      }
    
      function getDesligar(agent) {
        var gpioalarmstateb = agent.parameters;
        return db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').get()
          .then(doc => {
            const xalarmstateD = doc.data().gpioalarmstate;
            if (xalarmstateD) {
              db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').update({
                gpioalarmstate: false
              })
            }
            agent.add(`Gpioalarmstate is ${gpioalarmstateb} xalarmstate is  ${xalarmstateD}.`);
          });
      }
    
    
      function getAbrirr(agent) {
        var gpiogaragestateb = agent.parameters;
        return db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').get()
          .then(doc => {
            const xgaragestate = doc.data().gpiogaragestate;
            if (!xgaragestate) {
              db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').update({
                gpiogaragestate: true
              })
            }
            agent.add(`Gpiogaragestate is ${gpiogaragestateb} xgaragestate is  ${xgaragestate}.`);
          });
      }
    
      function getFechar(agent) {
        var gpiogaragestateb = agent.parameters;
        return db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').get()
          .then(doc => {
            const xgaragestateF = doc.data().gpiogaragestate;
            if (xgaragestateF) {
              db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').update({
                gpiogaragestate: false
              })
            }
            agent.add(`Gpiogaragestate is ${gpiogaragestateb} xgaragestate is  ${xgaragestateF}.`);
          });
      }
    
      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('Ligar', getLigar);
      intentMap.set('Desligar', getDesligar);
      intentMap.set('Abrir', getAbrirr);
      intentMap.set('Fechar', getFechar);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
    });
```

Comment: @Prisoner Tks. I saw your responses on dialogflow here on the stack and I liked it. iIn the link below I put photos of two of the code intents. I want a simple thing with 4 commands (Ligar, Desligar, Abrir and Fechar) that change firestore values. I haven't tried anything other than the above code and I don't know why it isn't working: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qXVx9ojFkRoKTKjCdXvZqemyNC4o041s?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ltgQJQaLttlz-aheI8G2p-AKvYQCEosG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was: I needed **async** before the 4 functions mentioned in the question and put **await** in the right place. Below I put an example that served for the first of the 4 functions:

```
  async function getLigar(agent) {

    return await db.collection('xxxxx').doc('yyyyy').get()
```